# Scrapy Nested Div Selection

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrapy Articles heading from 
https://time.com/

I want to select only those articles Link which are under "The Brief" Heading

I have tried to select nested div using this code

```
for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="column text-align-left visible-desktop visible-mobile last-column"]/div[@class="column-tout"]/a/@href').extract():
```

but it did not work

Can someone please help to extract those specific articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this `div` by content and next get all `following-sibling`:

```
for url in response.xpath('//div[.="The Brief"]/following-sibling::div//a/@href').extract():
```